# Using @font-face with url in less css

Tags: css, less

I have a url (`../font/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf`) How would I use @font-face with less css?

Tried this but doesn't work

```
.font(@fontName:"Lato"){
  font-family:@fontName;
}

.fontFace(@fontName:"Lato", @fontFile: '../font/Lato/Lato-Regular')
{
  font-family: @fontName;
  src: url('@{fontFile}.ttf');
}

.latoFont
{
  .font();
  @font-face{
   .fontFace();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write like this :-

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

[**Or Read More About how to use custom fonts for our websites.....**](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-font-face-or-how-to-use-a-custom-font-for-your-website)